# aws ec2 instance using instance profile role to connect to s3 bucket.. sql server 2022 backup getting operating system error 86

Tags: aws

Looking to see if anyone else having this issue.  I have a windows server 2019/sql server 2022 ec2 instance that has a instance profile using a role/policy to upload to an s3 bucket.  I created a policy to allow to list,read,write etc.. to the s3 bucket and have it attached to a role.  The role has been added to the ec2 instance.  Using the aws cli, and I can list the files in the bucket and upload to the bucket.  But in SSMS I try to run:

```
BACKUP DATABASE SampleDB
TO URL = 's3://xxxxxdemobucket/server1/sampledb.bak'
WITH FORMAT, COMPRESSION, MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 20971520;
```

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Cannot open backup device 's3://xxxxxdemobucket/server1/sampledb.bak'. Operating system error 86(The specified network password is not correct.).
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I read that you need to add aws credentials to sql server to upload to aws s3, but since I'm using the role in the instance profile I figure I shouldn't have too.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Only because I spent over a day figuring this out myself, I have some pointers for you, as well as other readers. Without assuming too much about your exact setup on AWS, try these tips in order and I am near certain you will get it fixed. Unfortunately, most AWS documentation revolves around users doing backups / restores from RDS, so it can be a bit of a struggle for someone trying to piece things together for EC2 hosted SQL Server instances!

### 1) Your URL is wrong

Instead of this...

```
BACKUP DATABASE SampleDB
TO URL = 's3://xxxxxdemobucket/server1/sampledb.bak'
```

You need something like this..

```
BACKUP DATABASE SampleDB
TO URL = 's3://xxxxxdemobucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/server1/sampledb.bak'
```

It's a bit of a misnomer, because your error will look something like this.

```
Cannot open backup device 's3://xxxxxdemobucket/server1/sampledb.bak'. Operating system error 86(The specified network password is not correct.).
```

Which makes it seems like a permission or password issue, but it's really that your **ec2 instance fails to resolve the s3 endpoint**... if this still doesn't fix it, keep reading, you may only be a few clicks away from this working!

### 2) You do need credentials for SQL Server

Yes, the IAM role will allow traffic between your EC2 instance and your S3 bucket, but for SQL Server to execute a backup from a URL, I am quite certain that you need to declare a set of credentials on your SQL Server instance like so.

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [s3://xxxxxdemobucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com] 
WITH 
    IDENTITY = 'S3 Access Key', 
    SECRET = '<ACCESS_KEY>:<SECRET_KEY>'
;
```

In order to get your **<ACCESS_KEY>** and **<SECRET_KEY>**, create a set of credentials for a new IAM user with full access to s3 (worry about least privileged after you get it working). After the credentials are created, if this is still not working, I am betting the last tip will be your solution!

### 3) Your VPC is missing the s3 endpoint

In order for your ec2 instance to resolve the following endpoint

```
xxxxxdemobucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

You need to "create a VPC endpoint" for the following "AWS service" and attach it to the VPC that is hosting your ec2 instance - since there are two AWS services with this name, you will want to select the one with **Gateway** as type.

```
com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3
```

After this endpoint is created, wait a few minutes for the endpoint status to show as "Available" in the endpoints tab of VPC section and give it another shot.

Good luck!!